# Elasticsearch - Nested value query inside field_value_factor

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I'm new to ES and am looking to create a searchable catalogue of products for users but I can't work out the way to encode different users having bought the same products.

I have an index full of products, and these products may have been bought multiple times by different users which I have represented using nesting. Some products have entries for all users, some will have none.

I need to create the ability to search the products and have products that the particular user has bought get higher scoring over others. My issue is that I don't know how to pull out this field inside the field_value_factor function as it may not exist for all products.

My closest try so far (thanks to Val) is:

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "query": "black toner",
                  "fields": [
                     "name",
                     "description"
                  ],
                  "tie_breaker": 0.3
               }
            },
            {
               "query": {
                  "function_score": {
                     "query": {
                        "bool": {
                           "must": [
                              {
                                 "multi_match": {
                                    "query": "black toner",
                                    "fields": [
                                       "name",
                                       "description"
                                    ],
                                    "tie_breaker": 0.3
                                 }
                              },
                              {
                                 "nested": {
                                    "path": "user",
                                    "query": {
                                       "term": {
                                          "user.userid": "MWUser2"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     "functions": [
                        {
                           "field_value_factor": {
                              "field": "user.count",
                              "modifier": "log1p",
                              "missing": 0
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

The issue here is that I cannot apply the ``` nested``path ``` to the `field_value_factor`, so this is always coming out as 0 and the user specific scoring boost isn't working. When the ``` nested``path ``` is applied around the entire `function_score` the first `multi_match` query on `description` and `name` does not work.

**EDIT 1**

Another way to do this may be to calculate the scores separately and then combine them. I can do this, but the `should` method of combining them will normalise the scores which is not what I want. So instead of doing `0.9 + 4` and `0.5 + 5` I get `0.7+0.7` for both. Is there any way around this?

```
{ 
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "should": [
            {
               "query": {
                  "multi_match": {
                      "use_dis_max": false, 
                     "query": "black super quality toner",
                     "fields": [
                        "name^3",
                        "description"
                     ],
                     "tie_breaker": 0.3
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "query": {
                  "nested": {
                     "path": "user",
                     "query": {
                        "function_score": {
                           "filter": {
                              "term": {
                                 "user.userid": "MWUser1"
                              }
                           },
                           "functions": [
                              {
                                 "field_value_factor": {
                                    "field": "user.count",
                                    "modifier": "log1p",
                                    "missing": 0
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

My mapping is:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "nest_type": {
      "properties": {
        "id" :             {"type":"string"},
        "company_code" :   {"type":"string"},
        "name" :           {"type":"string"},
        "description" :    {"type":"string"},
        "virtual_entity" : {"type":"boolean"},
        "created_at" :     {"type":"date"},
        "updated_at" :     {"type":"date"},
        "user": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "userid": {"type":"string"},
            "count": {"type":"short"},
            "last_bought": {"type":"date"}
          } 
        },
        "@timestamp" : {"type":"date"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some documents are:

```
{
  "id": "C8061X",
  "company_code": "MWCOMPCODE",
  "name": "Black LaserJet Toner Cartridge",
  "description": "- HP LaserJet C8061 Family Print Cartridges deliver extra sharp black text, smooth greyscales and fine detail in graphics.\n- HP LaserJet C8061 Family Print Cartridges with Smart Printing Technology with in-built reliability and rigorous quality testing ensure maximum printer uptime with minimum user intervention.\n- HP LaserJet C8061 Family Print Cartridges all-in-one design allow effortless installation and maintenance. Smart Printing Technology features monitoring of supplies status and usage information via the printers control panel or web browser.\n",
  "virtual_entity": false,
  "created_at": "2016-09-21T12:23:53.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2016-09-21T12:23:53.000Z",
  "user": [
    {
      "userid": "MWUser1",
      "count": 4,
      "last_bought": "2016-09-14T12:43:30.000Z"
    },
    {
      "userid": "MWUser2",
      "count": 2,
      "last_bought": "2016-09-14T10:00:00.000Z"
    }
  ],
  "@timestamp": "2016-09-21T13:38:30.077Z"
}
{
  "id": "C8061Y",
  "company_code": "MWCOMPCODE",
  "name": "Black LaserJet Toner Cartridge Super Quality",
  "description": "- HP LaserJet C8061 Family Print Cartridges deliver extra quality sharp black text, smooth greyscales and fine detail in graphics.\n- HP LaserJet C8061 Family Print Cartridges with Smart Printing Technology with in-built reliability and rigorous quality testing ensure maximum printer uptime with minimum user intervention.\n- HP LaserJet C8061 Family Print Cartridges all-in-one design allow effortless installation and maintenance. Smart Printing Technology features monitoring of supplies status and usage information via the printers control panel or web browser.\n",
  "virtual_entity": false,
  "created_at": "2016-09-21T12:23:53.000Z",
  "updated_at": "2016-09-21T12:23:53.000Z",
  "@timestamp": "2016-09-21T13:38:30.077Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the below. I ensure the documents satisfy the full-text search, and build up the score as a boosted combination of the full-text score and the log of the count of the user.

```
GET /nest_index_toy/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": {
            "multi_match": {
               "use_dis_max": false,
               "query": "black toner super quality",
               "fields": [
                  "name^3",
                  "description"
               ],
               "tie_breaker": 0.3,
               "boost": 2
            }
         },
         "should": [
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "use_dis_max": false,
                  "query": "black toner super quality",
                  "fields": [
                     "name^3",
                     "description"
                  ],
                  "tie_breaker": 0.3,
                  "boost": 2
               }
            },
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "user",
                  "query": {
                     "function_score": {
                        "filter": {
                           "term": {
                              "user.userid": "MWUser1"
                           }
                        },
                        "functions": [
                           {
                              "field_value_factor": {
                                 "field": "user.count",
                                 "modifier": "log1p",
                                 "missing": 0
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to build the condition on the nested user into a `nested` query which then wraps your `function_score` query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "user",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "user.userid": "MWUser1"
              }
            },
            {
              "function_score": {
                "query": {
                  "multi_match": {
                    "query": "black toner",
                    "fields": [
                      "name",
                      "description"
                    ],
                    "tie_breaker": 0.3
                  }
                },
                "field_value_factor": {
                  "field": "user.userid.count",
                  "modifier": "log1p",
                  "missing": 10
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 5
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't know that you could put a query inside the function_score but this doesn't give me quite what I want.

When using "must" no results are returned. When I use "should" only documents that have an entry for "MWUser1" are returned, but his `count` value is not being used. When the query is rerun with "MWUser2" the "C8061X" document gets the same score, but the MWUser2.count is 2 instead of 4.

If this query can return a score only based on the selected users `count` then I think I can combine it with another query to do the full-text matching?

Comment: Hmm, maybe the `multi_match` query on `name` and `description` needs to be extracted at the top level into a `bool/must`. Can you try?

Comment: Ah - thanks for this. I **copied** the `multi_match` up to the top level and using `should` this query returns products without any `user` information and `user` previously bought products are at the top.

However it looks like it's taking the "first" `user.count` rather than the selected one. Any idea how to debug/check what the query is doing?

Comment: use `bool/must` instead of `bool/should`. Also maybe update your question with the query you have now

Comment: I've updated the question with my best result so far. I need `should` at the outer level otherwise only documents that have a user will be found (from the second query). The issue I am left with is that the scoring is not working as I can't work out how to add the `nest` around the `field_value_factor` only, as if I wrap it around the `multi_match` inside the `function_score` it makes that part of the query return no documents.

Comment: Inside your `function-score` query you have `query` two times, remove one

Comment: I don't understand how this would work. When I attempt to use `function_score` within a `nested` query, I get the following error message, `"[nested] query does not support [function_score]"`. Is this supported in a later version of Elasticsearch? I'm using v2.1.0.

Comment: @StevenOxley - I'm using v2.4.0 and am able to do `nested { .. query{ function_score`

@Val - Inside a `nested` query it is not possible to reference the outer fields so I cannot do `nested { ... function_score`. I have two separate queries: 1)the full-text score and 2)score=count of MWUser1. It is possible to just ADD these _scores? Using `should` normalises the scores of each subquery so instead of doing eg `0.9 + 4` and `0.5 + 10` it does `0.7 +0.7 = 1.4` and `0.7+0.7=1.4`